# VLC media element, VLC is unable to open the mrl

Tags: c#, media, vlc, uwp-xaml, libvlc

I am making an UWP app which includes VLC Media Element, as can be seen on this link : https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement

I am following the sample code to play the video files as on the github project.( which I mentioned above). But sometimes it gives following error.

> Your input can t be opened vlc is unable to open the mrl
> winrt://{GUID-string-token-is-here} Check the log for more details.

I have checked the log file in apppackage/localstoragecache folder and I found following errors in the log.:

> [core] (../../src/video_output/display.c:934) Failed to change zoom
>
> [core] (../../src/video_output/display.c:949) Failed to set on top
>
> [core] (../../src/video_output/display.c:973) Failed to change source AR
>
> [core] (../../src/video_output/display.c:1055) Failed to change Viewpoint
>
> [core] (../../src/video_output/display.c:934) Failed to change zoom
>
> [core] (../../src/video_output/display.c:973) Failed to change source AR

I think the error messages has nothing to do with my xaml or C# implementation (because it looks like pure problem of VLC or libvlc media library, which is used behind vlc Media Element for UWP), but I want still provide the code just in case.

**XAML**

```
<vlc:MediaElement Style="{StaticResource VLCStyle}" 
                  x:Name="Media">
</vlc:MediaElement>
```

**C#**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //SingleVideoToPlay is just an object of class video which I am using in my app.
    PlayNextFile(SingleVideoToPlay);
}
private void PlayNextFile(Video VideoToPlay)
{
    var FILE_TOKEN = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(VideoToPlay.file);
    Media.PosterSource = VideoToPlay.Thumbnail;
    Media.Source = null;
    Media.Source = $"winrt://{FILE_TOKEN}";
}

public class Video
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string Views { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public StorageFile file { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [this sample](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement/tree/master/SampleApp)? It works well in my side.

Comment: yes I have and same error occurs in my machine but I have tried it another virtual machine and it works fine on that machine I guess its some sort of problem with my machine but don't know the exact reason :/